# Protractor: select a form element using label

Tags: javascript, testing, protractor

I'm using protractor and I'm trying to select a form using it's label.

Let's take an example. I have this form with several input:

```
<form>
    <label for="name">Name</label>
    <input type="text" id="name">
    <label for="address">Address</label>
    <input type="text" id="address">
    <label for="email">Email</label>
    <input type="text" id="email">
</form>
```

My step definition should be something like that:

```
this.When(/^I fill input identified by label "([^"]*)" with value "([^"]*)"$/, function(labelName, value, callback){        
   ...
});
```

I need to write this step definition because I'm using protractor with cucumber.js, so the person who will run the test should be able to fill a form knowing only the label, without inspect html code to retrieve class, id or other attributes.

I've found [this question](https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/191) on github but I would like to know if there is a better method to do this.

Can anyone help me to solve this problem? I don't like to ask code snippets to other developers but I really don't know how to proceed and I can't find documentation about this problem.

**IMPORTANT: I'm NOT using Angularjs**

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can find the `label` element by text and then get the [following sibling](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Axes/following-sibling) `input` element:

```
var input = element(by.xpath("//label[. = '" + labelName + "']/following-sibling::input"));
input.sendKeys(value);
```

Answer (score 0):

I recently ran into this problem because I was looking to find input fields by label instead of ID (so I could focus more on testing the interface than the implementation)

Here's the xpath snippet I came up with:

```
function findElementByLabel(labelText, opt_parentElement) {
    const using = opt_parentElement || document;
    const xpath = `//input[@id=string(//label[. = '${labelText}']/@for)]`;
    return document.evaluate(xpath, using, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE).singleNodeValue;
};
```

It starts by grabbing the label element with the provided content, grabs the for attribute, then uses that to find the input with the matching id.